# CGPoint: No exact matches in call to initializer

Tags: swift

CGPoint init - `No exact matches in call to initializer` error

What's wrong with my code? so ..

[image]

```
    let ctx: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    ctx.setLineWidth(1/UIScreen.main.scale);
    ctx.setLineCap(.square)
    ctx.setLineJoin(.round)
    ctx.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)

    for i in 0...3 {
        ctx.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 40*i))
        ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, y: CGFloat(40*i)))
    }
```

Comment: First, a small bit of criticism? Don't post screenshots of your code - it isn't searchable, and not easy to duplicate. (I'm sure some will downvote or vote to close because of it.) Could you post a bit more code for context? Where is this code? If it's in an initializer, what is the value of `UIScreen.main.bounds`? I'm thinking that this is where the actual issue is, but it could be `ctx`. But if you could make your code something to duplicate, it would greatly help us to find the issue.

Comment: I have add code to content, it ok now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you pass a `CGFloat` to x, and an `Int` to y. So swift is looking in vain for a `CGPoint(x: CGFloat, y: Int)` initializer.

```
CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: CGFloat(40 * i))
```

Should work